# Split an array of checkboxes then wrap them into a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a webform generator as it is the only way for me to make a form via my CMS. I cannot edit the html code manually when it is rendered, so I have to manipulate with jQuery. For checkboxes the markup outputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_0" value="Masonry walls">Masonry walls
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_1" value="Attic">Attic
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_2" value="Non-masonry walls">Non-masonry walls
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_3" value="Roof">Roof
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_4" value="Foundation walls">Foundation walls
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_5" value="Floor">Floor
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_6" value="Ceiling">Ceiling
<br>
```

I would like them to look like the this instead:

```
<label class="c-input c-checkbox">
    <input id="radioStacked1" name="radio-stacked" type="checkbox">
    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
    Toggle this custom checkbox
</label>
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default form has a container you can target, that'd be ideal, so you can replace the whole block in one shot without having to deal with text nodes:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_0" value="Masonry walls">Masonry walls
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_1" value="Attic">Attic
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_2" value="Non-masonry walls">Non-masonry walls
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_3" value="Roof">Roof
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_4" value="Foundation walls">Foundation walls
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_5" value="Floor">Floor
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_1946925" id="CAT_Custom_1946925_6" value="Ceiling">Ceiling
  <br>
</div>
```

From there, you can iterate over each checkbox, collect a few values, and concatenate them all into a string value. Once that's done, just replace the contents of the container with the new markup:

```
var _html = "";
var $container = $('.container');
$container.find('input').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  _name = $this.attr('name');
  _id = $this.attr('id');
  _value = $this.attr('value');

  _html += '<label class="c-input c-checkbox">';
  _html += '  <input id="' + _id + '" name="' + _name + '" type="checkbox" value="' + _value + '">';
  _html += '  <span class="c-indicator"></span>';
  _html += _value;
  _html += '</label><br>';
});
$container.html(_html);
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/moz17sch/